# Linux network access control c interface

Tags: c, linux, networking

Is there a C interface like fanotify in Linux for monitoring network events and permission management?

I want to write a firewall program in c that I need to have control on network accesses in Linux.

EDIT: what I want?
I want to have fully access to network events, network hardware and devices, in-coming and out-going packets and... and fully control of this events and devices and... completely like a file access control interface for example fanotify.

Comment: For network events you can take a look at NFQUEUE.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about what information you want to get or what exactly you want to control.

Comment: @Bodo okey done! thanks

Comment: @Cheatah tnx. can have control using this or it is just for monitoring?

Comment: I think even with your edit your question lacks details, so it is still too broad to answer. Describing the use cases in detail might help. Firewalls on Linux are normally based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables NFQUEUE is one of the available options. You should search for documentation and examples. (Google search returns e.g. https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/using-nfqueue-and-libnetfilter_queue/ and https://www.forwardproxy.com/2019/01/using-nfqueue-to-build-your-own-firewall/)